# Renaming beginning of file on windows using ren

Tags: windows, cmd, rename

I have an issue where I want to replace part of a filename with another string.

So I have a file, lets call it `dog_cat_pig.txt` and I want to replace the string `dog` with `elephant` to get `elephant_cat_pig.txt`.

Using `ren dog* elephant*` renames the file `elephantpig.txt` and overwrites existing characters after the sourceMask.

How can I use this command to rename the file `elephant_cat_pig.txt`?

Comment: Wildcards in CMD are not regular expressions. "dog*" generates the list of files to rename. Each file is renamed using the wildcard expression "elephant*" . This starts with characters 0-7 as "elephant"; then continues with the subsequent characters from the original name, up to the extension (e.g. "pig"); and then finishes with the ".txt" extension verbatim since you didn't modify the file extension in the wildcard expression.

Comment: Consider using a language that supports regular expressions, such as Python or PowerShell.